# RMI codebase concept

Tags: java, rmi

I have a difficulty in understanding codebase concept. Could somebody explain it in more detail ? I can implement remote interface on server and client will be able to use that object, so why codebase is needed ?

Comment: Why don't you read a tutorial?

Comment: RMI moves objects, not classes.